# Verifying Perl Arguments to a Subprocesses

Tags: perl, subprocess

So I am a beginning Perl programmer. I have been using it for about a month, however only in the last week or so have I been using it for anything other than sysadmin type tasks. In doing so I ran into the following question,

Perl subprocesses are really flexible, and they don't impose many/any constraints on arguments you pass in. How is it possible to either enforce the number of arguments and/or check whether they're references, scalars etc etc?

To clarify, here's what I currently do for Perl subprocesses:

```
sub mySub{
    ($a, $b) = @_;
    continue and use these methods
 }
```

But this provides no guarantees about what `$a` and `$b` hold. Is there anyway to make sure they contain values, say a reference for `$a` and a scalar for `$b`?

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT: When I said scalar for `$b` I mean containing an integer, and not being a reference to some other datastructure.

Comment: [What Perl modules are useful for validating subroutine arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433070/what-perl-modules-are-useful-for-validating-subroutine-arguments), [Is checking Perl function arguments worth it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330599/is-checking-perl-function-arguments-worth-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Params::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Params-Validate-1.06/lib/Params/Validate.pm) module, it provides wide possibilities of checking the argument list.

In your case, something like

```
validate_pos(@_, { type => HASHREF | ARRAYREF }, { type => SCALAR })
```

would do it (note that it doesn't have a single type for "ref"). It dies when the parameters don't match.

Comment: +1, this is also the [recommendation from the official Perl 5 wiki](https://socialtext.net/perl5/common_tasks#Validating_data).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify this using subroutine prototypes:

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes for a full explanation.

*sub taking a single scalar*

```
sub foo($) {
    my $scalar = shift;
}
```

*sub taking two scalars*

```
sub bar($$) {
    my ($scalar1, $scalar2) = @_;
}
```

*sub taking an array*

```
sub baz (+*) {
    my $arrayref = shift;
}
```

*sub taking a hash*

```
sub quux (+%) {
    my $hashref = shift;
}
```

Comment: This just governs how they behave when called as operators, when called with () it provides no guarantees

Answer (score 0):

To check whether $a is a ref you can use

```
if(ref($a))
```

To check what type of reference it is you can use

if (ref($a) eq "HASH")  { #or ARRAY

Answer (score 0):

You can perform tests on the arguments to see what they contain. However, there is no point in checking whether a scalar is a scalar.

```
sub mySub{
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    if (ref $a eq 'ARRAY') { ... } # check for array ref
    continue and use these methods
 }
```

A variable such as `$b` is already a scalar, and can only contain scalar values. A reference, for example, is a scalar value. So you will need to be more specific about what you want the variable to contain.

Counting the arguments is as simple as counting any array:

```
sub foo {
    my $n_args = @_;  # array is scalar context returns its size
    if (@_ < 4) {     # same thing
    ...
}
```

In order to validate for example an alphanumeric string, you can do

```
if ($arg =~ /^[\w\s]+$/) {  # contains only whitespace and alphanumerics
```